# Create Custom Directive for Custom Check box in Angular js

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Hi any one please help me...

I want create custom directive for custom check box in Angular js,

I am done creating box, i want create check mark when we click checked.

HTML Code ::::

```
 <my-checkbox ng-transclude class="customCheeckBox" style="margin:5px;"></my-checkbox>
```

Custom Directive code:

```
App.directive('myCheckbox', function(){
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      transclude:true,
      template: '<div class="checkbox" ng-class="{checked: isChecked}" ng-click="toggleMe()"></div>',
      scope: {
        isChecked: '=?'
      },
      link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.isChecked = true;

        scope.toggleMe = function () {
          scope.isChecked = !(scope.isChecked);  
          console.log('clicked');
        }
      }
  }});
```

CSS code:

```
.checked {
  background-color:red;
}
.customCheeckBox{
    border: 1px solid black;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
}
```

I want check mark for when we selected the check box.

Can any please help me

Comment: Can you share plunk???

Comment: can u just post a image made in paint or something so that we can know better what you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi @Reena  [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/b3xiv6vPLVO9frexRbYx?p=preview)

Comment: You want same as this http://jsfiddle.net/zy7Rg/2/

Comment: Have a read https://github.com/fronteed/iCheck/issues/62

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget about: `require: "ngModel"` https://jsfiddle.net/az3rq4na/.
Your checkbox should contain any model to show it's state. Read more about **ngModelController** at official site.

Comment: Hi @Ivan Burnaev , Thanks for your answer, but i want tick mark. when user checked that time color only changed, but instead of color change i want make act like HTML textbox. Can you please let me know if you know.

Comment: I've modified my `fiddle` https://jsfiddle.net/az3rq4na/. But you can use any icons or css styles.

Comment: this dirctive is not working in IE8, can any one help me about

Comment: Hi @Ivan Burnaev, i need small help, i am getting always false when i checked or unchecked the check box, can you please help me why i am getting always false, please.

Comment: Hmm... You can check the same fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/az3rq4na/2/. Model changes correctlly.